# Moving turtles from extension in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am working on creating a traffic grid in NetLogo. I would like to create an extension to go along with the model that contains the rules for updating the grid and moves the cars, turtles in this case, accordingly.

I am having trouble getting the turtles to actually move. The set of turtles is being passed as an argument to the function that should update the turtles' positions. I tried using setVariable(), but it isn't working for me:

```
    Turtle car = args[0].getTurtle();        
    car.setVariable(AgentVariableNumbers.VAR_XCOR, 29);
    car.setVariable(AgentVariableNumbers.VAR_YCOR, 40);
```

Since it is a traffic grid, I am focused on just moving the turtles forward for now. Is there a way (other than using setVariable) to move turtles from an extension?

Comment: when you say "it isn't working for me", you mean you get an error message, or unexpected behavior, or what?

Comment: I would have thought that the [Controlling](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs) interface rather than an Extension would be better for this purpose.

Comment: The code above is in a try-catch block and I am getting an engine exception. I am much more familiar with the Controlling API, so that might be my next move. Thanks!